# Please help to find out why the code works in such manner (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i've been working on a primitive code and got the unexpected result.

```
var one = prompt("Enter the number", "4");
var age = parseInt(one);
if (age >= 14 || age <= 90) {
    console.log("Correct");
} else {
    console.log("Wrong")
}
```

When I put 100, for example, it says "Correct" instead of "Wrong".

Would you be so kind to answer why it works in such manner.

Comment: `age >= 14 || age <= 90` if age is greater/equal to 14, `OR` age is less than/equal to 90. 100 is greater than 14.

Comment: Because the age is greater than 14. Simple boolean logic true || false = true

Answer (score 1):

You are using an or operation, so when `age` is 100 the first part of the OR operation is true which means that the entire OR condition is true because `true OR false` is true.

You need to use and `AND` operator

```
var one = prompt("Enter the number", "4");
var age = parseInt(one);
if (age >= 14 && age <= 90) {
    console.log("Correct");
} else {
    console.log("Wrong")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any number will return true, because any number is `> 14` OR `< 90`.

If you need the age to be *between 14 and 90*, do it this way:

```
if ( age >=14 && age <= 90 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I  got ur Requirement instead of Using OR Operator i.e "||" you should use AND Operator i.e "&&" then u will get the desired result its a logical error